# COUNT returns double values when using multiple joins

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

When I run this query I get neatly the results I want.

```
SELECT 
referer_trackings.cookie_first_url AS url,
sum(purchases.price) AS sales, 
count(purchases.id) AS volume
FROM purchases
JOIN referer_trackings 
ON referer_trackings.trackable_id = purchases.id
JOIN items
ON purchases.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.seller_id = '39'
AND referer_trackings.trackable_type = 'Purchase'
AND purchases.workflow_state = 'payment_successful'
GROUP BY referer_trackings.cookie_first_url
```

This returns:

```
url             sales          volume
======================================
UrlName1.com    8743           332
UrlName2.com    234            123
UrlName3.com    2352           2345
```

This is correct, but I also store landing page views in another separate table because what I really need is this:

```
url             sales          volume       landing_page_views
===============================================================
UrlName1.com    8743           332          34563
UrlName2.com    234            123          52443
UrlName3.com    2352           2345         84563
```

To get this result I run this query:

```
SELECT 
referer_trackings.cookie_first_url AS url,
sum(purchases.price) AS sales, 
count(purchases.id) AS volume,
COUNT(DISTINCT product_landing_page_views.id) AS ulpvs
FROM purchases
JOIN referer_trackings 
ON referer_trackings.trackable_id = purchases.id
JOIN items
ON purchases.item_id = items.id
JOIN product_landing_page_views
ON product_landing_page_views.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.seller_id = '39'
AND referer_trackings.trackable_type = 'Purchase'
AND purchases.workflow_state = 'payment_successful'
GROUP BY referer_trackings.cookie_first_url
```

This results in data that looks doubled and is WAY more than the actual counts. I know this is due to the fact that calling

```
JOIN product_landing_page_views
ON product_landing_page_views.item_id = items.id
```

adds rows to the results and thus multiplies the counts.

So my question is: how do I make sure that when joining the product_landing_page_views table the query still yields the correct counts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT 
referer_trackings.cookie_first_url AS url,
sum(purchases.price) AS sales, 
count(purchases.id) AS volume,
product_landing_page_views.ulpvs
FROM purchases
JOIN referer_trackings 
ON referer_trackings.trackable_id = purchases.id
JOIN items
ON purchases.item_id = items.id
JOIN (SELECT item_id, count(*) as ulpvs from product_landing_page_views GROUP BY item_id) as product_landing_page_views
ON product_landing_page_views.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.seller_id = '39'
AND referer_trackings.trackable_type = 'Purchase'
AND purchases.workflow_state = 'payment_successful'
GROUP BY referer_trackings.cookie_first_url
```

(This is assuming I'm understanding the structure of your table correctly.  Apologies if not).